# Legend not show in the graph

Tags: r

I was trying to build the stock prices graph but I am facing difficulties. My legends are not shown in the graph although I have return in the code correctly. I am new to R so I couldn't find any error.

## THIS IS MY CODE

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

tickers <- c("AAPL", "AMZN" , "MSFT" ,"FB")

portfolioPrices <- NULL
  for (Ticker in tickers)
      portfolioPrices <- cbind(portfolioPrices,
                       getSymbols.yahoo(Ticker, from="2017-01-01", 
   periodicity = "weekly", auto.assign=FALSE)[,4])


  portfolioPrices <- portfolioPrices[apply(portfolioPrices,1,function(x) all(!is.na(x))),]

  colnames(portfolioPrices) <- tickers

   plot(portfolioPrices, legend = tickers)


   scaledData <- scale(portfolioPrices)
   plot(scaledData, legend = tickers)
```

## THIS IS MY GRAPH[image]

I want the tickers to be as legends but it is not showing. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can  check [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-legends-to-plots-in-r-software-the-easiest-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  `addLegend` command like below, it should work(Attached is the outcome form my desktop):

```
plot(portfolioPrices)
addLegend("topleft", on=0, 
          legend.names = tickers, 
          lty=c(1, 1,1,1), lwd=c(1, 1,1,1)
          )
```

From documentation:

> addLegend(legend.loc = "topright", legend.names = NULL, col = NULL,
>   ncol = 1, on = 0, ...)

**legend.loc**

> legend.loc places a legend into one of nine locations on the chart:
>   bottomright, bottom, bottomleft, left, topleft, top, topright, right,
>   or center.

**legend.names**

> character vector of names for the legend. If NULL, the column names of
>   the current plot object are used.

**col**

> fill colors for the legend. If NULL, the colorset of the current plot
>   object data is used.

**ncol**

> number of columns for the legend

**on**

> panel number to draw on. A new panel will be drawn if on=NA. The
>   default, on=0, will add to the active panel. The active panel is
>   defined as the panel on which the most recent action was performed.
>   Note that only the first element of on is checked for the default
>   behavior to add to the last active panel.

**Output:**

[image]